# ASP.NET MVC external

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

Is there a way to externalize entity framework data annotation in configuration file ?

For example with doctrine in php you can determine your model specifications with annotations or in external yml/xml file.

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, you can use the [fluent api](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx) to separate your concerns.

Comment: You can eventually uses a metadata class as statetd here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664465(v=pandp.50).aspx